# Youtube API - is there a way to get real-time information about youtube channels like new video being uploaded?

Tags: push-notification, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-developer-tools, websub

I am trying to build an application that does something every time a new video is uploaded to one or more channels.

My search lead me to [the Youtube Data API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications). This is a push notification service that sends information every time a channel that you are subscribed to makes one of the following changes: 
 1. new video upload, 2. change in title, and 3. change in the video description.

I implemented this in python and I subscribed to receive updates on my channel. I was able to see that the subscription was successful using the [pubshub/ websub tool](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe) . However, when changes were made to the videos on the channel I was subscribed to, I did not receive any push notifications.

some said that there's a huge delay ( it should not be because youtube claims it's near real-time), but then I saw the issue [tracker page for this feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35175433) which basically says that the feature is broken.

So, I wanted to know if there is any other mechanism that I can try to do this? or is there someone who has tried this, and it's working?

Comment: It might help to include your Python code so others can reproduce the issue. The [most recent comments here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181221330) indicate that it might be resolved.